# Comparing CSV record to records in a MSAccess table

Tags: ms-access, vba

My function should take a given table, the number field, the Phone company field, and find if any of the Phone Companies have changed with the database and then set the database's Phone company to the newly uploaded one.

Although I tested it with a table with a table in MSAccess, and it did catch records where they didn't match and then update them accordingly.

However, it wouldn't work with a Table and an imported CSV file. There's no error that pops up, but mainly when I test the outputs with message boxes, it seems to think that "ATT" and "ATT" are not equal to each other. Are there some invisible spaces / tab characters in the CSV file?

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sr As DAO.Recordset

'Open Billingcsv
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select [" & NumberName & "], [" & PhoneCompanyName & "] from [" & TableName & "] Where [" & _
NumberName & "] is not null ")

'Set tblPhoneDept
Set sr = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblPhoneDept", dbOpenTable)

sr.Index = "PrimaryKey"
If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do While rs.EOF <> True
            'check if phone company matches
            sr.Seek "=", rs.Fields("[" & NumberName & "]")
            If Not sr.NoMatch Then
                If sr![PhoneCompany] <> rs.Fields("[" & PhoneCompanyName & "]") Then
                    MsgBox sr![PhoneCompany] & " " & sr![Number] & " " & rs.Fields("[" & PhoneCompanyName & "]") & " " & rs.Fields("[" & NumberName & "]")
                    CurrentDb.Execute "Update [tblPhoneDept] SET [PhoneCompany] = " & rs.Fields("[" & PhoneCompanyName & "]") & _
                    " WHERE [number] = '" & rs.Fields("[" & NumberName & "]") & "'"
                    MsgBox sr![PhoneCompany] & " " & sr![Number] & " " & rs.Fields("[" & PhoneCompanyName & "]") & " " & rs.Fields("[" & NumberName & "]")
                Stop
                End If
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
End If
```

CSV File:

```
WirelessNumber PhoneCompany
(xxx) xxx-xxxx  ATT
(yyy) xxx-xxxx  ATT2
(zzz) xxx-xxxx  ATT3
(aaa) xxx-xxxx  Sprint
(bbb) xxx-xxxx  ATT2
(ccc) xxx-xxxx  ATT
(ddd) xxx-xxxx  ATT3
```

tblPhoneDept

```
Number PhoneCompany
(xxx) xxx-xxxx  ATT
(yyy) xxx-xxxx  ATT6 
(zzz) xxx-xxxx  ATT5
(aaa) xxx-xxxx  Sprint
(bbb) xxx-xxxx  ATT2
(ccc) xxx-xxxx  ATT
(ddd) xxx-xxxx  ATT3
```

Comment: What would be better?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102641/for-arsarc   ... can we try chat?

Comment: I believe you'll do well to choose between two approaches -- one using `DAO recordsets`, the other relying on `DLookup()`.  Using both typically doesn't make sense.  I am not sure which to recommend.  The code needs refactoring in general.

Comment: Why are you doing this with the VBA looping? Just use SQL join query on the two sets. Do they share unique identifiers?

Comment: The CSV file is deleted after the data gets imported. The CSV comes from the Phone Company's site (ATT, Verizon, Sprint) I just gave a simplified version of what I needed. A secretary uploads a new CSV every month to generate a billing report for each department, I'm just trying to automate her process as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link your CSV file as an Excel external linked table, create a join between the two tables (creating your SQL if the TableName is a parameter (you will find good posts on this site), and then run an update query on all selected records.

Comment: Ok I did something kinda similar, imported it into its table and then ran the comparison. It works, thank you.

Comment: @arsarc, I hope by comparison you mean an SQL join query and not the VBA recordset looping as I mentioned in comments above.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I ended up importing the CSV File into its table (tblATTPhonesBilling), deleting the CSV file, then passing along the Date to help filter the most recent CSV entries.

Passed variables like this from the "Import CSV" section:

CheckChangedPhoneCompanies "tblATTPhonesBilling", "Wireless Number", "Billing Account Number", "Market Cycle End Date", MarketCycleDateStr

Code changed to just filter it:

```
Public Function CheckChangedPhoneCompanies(TableName As String, NumberName As String, PhoneCompanyName As String, BillingCycleDateName As String, BillingCycleDate As String)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sr As DAO.Recordset

    'Open Billingcsv
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select [" & NumberName & "], [" & PhoneCompanyName & "] from [" & TableName & "] Where [" & _
    NumberName & "] is not null AND [" & BillingCycleDateName & "] = #" & BillingCycleDate & "# ")

    'Set tblPhoneDept
    Set sr = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblPhoneDept", dbOpenTable)

    sr.Index = "PrimaryKey"
    If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
            rs.MoveFirst
            Do While rs.EOF <> True
                'check if phone company matches
                sr.Seek "=", rs.Fields("[" & NumberName & "]")
                If Not sr.NoMatch Then
                    If sr![PhoneCompany] <> rs.Fields("[" & PhoneCompanyName & "]") Then
                        MsgBox sr![PhoneCompany] & " " & sr![Number] & " " & rs.Fields("[" & PhoneCompanyName & "]") & " " & rs.Fields("[" & NumberName & "]")
                        CurrentDb.Execute "Update [tblPhoneDept] SET [PhoneCompany] = " & rs.Fields("[" & PhoneCompanyName & "]") & _
                        " WHERE [number] = '" & rs.Fields("[" & NumberName & "]") & "'"
                        MsgBox sr![PhoneCompany] & " " & sr![Number] & " " & rs.Fields("[" & PhoneCompanyName & "]") & " " & rs.Fields("[" & NumberName & "]")
                    Stop
                    End If
                End If
                rs.MoveNext
            Loop
    End If
End Function
```

I still have no idea why it doesn't work when comparing directly with a CSV file but this works with what I needed.